# JSP MySQL error

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp

i'm trying to get data from Mysql db to a .jsp page :

```
  <%

  List list = connection.getBookList();
  int id = 0;
  String box = null;

  Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();

  while (it.hasNext()) {
      id = Integer.parseInt(it.next());
      out.print("<tr>");
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          out.print("<td>");
          out.print(it.next());
          out.print("</td>");
  }
  out.print("<td>");
  box = "<input name=r" + id + " type='checkbox'>";
  out.print(box);
  out.print("</td>");
  out.print("</tr>");
 }
%>
```

here is the method in my class of db  retrival:

```
public List getBookList() throws SQLException
   {
      List  BookList = new ArrayList();


      ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM book" );



      while ( results.next() ) {
         BookBean  view  = new BookBean();

        view.setID(results.getString( 1 ));
        view.setName(results.getString( 2 ));
        view.setDescription(results.getString( 3));
        view.setCatID(results.getString( 4));
        view.setUID(results.getString(5 ));
        view.setDateAdded(results.getString( 6 ));
        view.setPicThumb(results.getString( 7 ));
        view.setPicLarge(results.getString( 8 ));




         BookList.add(view);
      }

      return BookList;
   }
```

if though is there any help to print my data in a jsp page within the way the upper method is written? 
i think the (view) makes the difference isn't it?

Comment: What is the problem now

Comment: @Anas Jamal Abu Sall -  I am clear about your problem.

Comment: your list is a list of BookBean, you can't use an Iterator<String>... look for logs.

Comment: What do you want your view to render?

Comment: Providing a description of what is wrong would be nice. Like is there any errors? What output do you get?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 bookshare.DBconnect.getBookList(DBconnect.java:146)
 org.apache.jsp.newjsp_jsp._jspService(newjsp_jsp.java:154)

Comment: i want to render in a jsp or html page

Comment: org.apache.jsp.newjsp_jsp._jspService(newjsp_jsp.java:154)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)

Comment: according to the function upper of getBookList(); how can i invoke and render results in a .jsp page?!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your iteration should be with `BookBean` and not with `String`

```
<%

  List list = connection.getBookList();
  int id = 0;
  String box = null;

  Iterator<BookBean> it = list.iterator();

  while (it.hasNext()) {

      BookBean view = it.next();
      out.print("<tr>");
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          out.print("<td>");

          //if you have a getter method in bean
          out.print(view.getId());

          out.print("</td>");
  }
  out.print("<td>");
  box = "<input name=r" + view.getId() + " type='checkbox'>";
  out.print(box);
  //out.print(view.getName());
  out.print("</td>");
  out.print("</tr>");
 }
%>
```

Comment: this code gives me null pointer excp.
java.lang.NullPointerException
 bookshare.DBconnect.getBookList(DBconnect.java:184)
 org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:92)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

Comment: The exception is happening in `DBconnect.java:184`. Can you tell me what is the content in line number `184`. Make sure the `statement` is `not null` and initialized properly in the `getBookList` method.